# Android: takePicture hangs

Tags: android, camera

I am trying to take a photo but it hangs when takePicture is called. No exception is generated. My code runs in an AsyncTask which is launced from a service. No activity is used and none MUST be used. I'm running this on Android 2.3.6. I can wait minutes and the onPictureTaken is never called.

Code:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;

public class CameraAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> implements Camera.PictureCallback
{
  private Camera camera;

  @Override
  protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params)
  {
    this.camera = Camera.open();
    this.camera.takePicture(null, null, (PictureCallback) this);
    this.camera.release();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Boolean succeeded)
  {
  }

  public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
  {
  }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call this.camera.startPreview() before taking photo, and stopPreview() after.
Also if you call release, as you are doing in your example, your callback will never get executed

Answer (score 0):

camera.takePicture cannot be called through background thread is must be through main thread